# Android Profile name from Facebook login is null

Tags: java, android

```
protected void getLoginDetails(LoginButton login_button){
    // Callback registration
    login_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult login_result) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Drawer.class);
            AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

                }
            };
            accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
            ProfileTracker profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {

                }
            };
            profileTracker.startTracking();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            user_name = profile.getFirstName();
            intent.putExtra("Name",user_name);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // code for cancellation
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            //  code to handle error
        }
    });
}
```

Hi, I'm trying to obtain the Profile Name after the user logged in(Facebook Login).

I have a Facebook Log in button which after the user log in, it will get the user profile name and sent with intent to another activity. But the error is that profile.getFirstName() is on null object. And the app stopped working (after logged in).

Is there any good way to solve this problem?, I try to avoid using GraphAPI. I just need a profile name.

Comment: Did you call callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); ?

Comment: Try bellow code

Comment: Yes, I called it inside onActivityResult method.  callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);